# Local Website page/web browser that executes python scripts instead of a terminal

Tags: python, web, arduino, server-side

I'm having trouble with PyScript, there were a lot of errors when I ran PyScript with HTML with inspect.

Is there a way for a pure python script be executed by a website locally, that can support functionality for these imports:

*import os
import serial
import win32api
from mss import mss
import numpy as np
import cv2*

> I'm using python as the middle bridge to my web browser to my arduino instead of node.js since python has more capabilities within my knowledge since I main python.

As said before I have tried PyScript but it was an javascript extension that doesn't have what I need it to do. I expected it execute python scripts acting its main like a terminal but it had errors even without my python.

```
<py-env> - paths:
- /spotify.py </py-env>
```

Comment: I'm currently trying Flask and Django but I would appreciate someone who has greater knowledge on what I can do here

Comment: Also I prefer using web browsers specifically with my project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.